# How to make splay tree with parent and child pointers in lisp

Tags: recursion, lisp, common-lisp, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I have this node structure defined as

```
(defstruct node 
  parent
  left
  right
  data)
```

When I fill in the parent node, is there any way to do it in such a way that avoids an infinite recursion in computing the parent?

For example: Say I have a node `(A :parent B :left 2 :right 3 :data nil)`, and a node `(B :parent nil :left 4 :right A :data nil)`. When you evalutate the parent of A, you get an infinite recursion (Parent of A is B -> B's right is A -> Parent of A is B -> ...). Is there a way to avoid this while keeping mlg(n) performance on all splay tree operations?

I appreciate it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The infinite recursion probably happens as part of the printing. You can avoid this by:

- Don't print the circular structure
- Enable circle-detection in the standard printer: `(setf *print-circle* t)`